# Django templates: testing if variable is in list or dict

Tags: django, templates

was wondering if there is a way to test if a variable is inside of a list or dict in django using the built in tags and filters.

Ie: `{% if var|in:the_list %}`

I don't see it in the docs, and will attempt something custom if not, but I don't want to do something that has already been done.

Thanks

Answer (score 41):

In Django 1.2, you can just do

```
{% if var in the_list %}
```

as you would in Python.

Otherwise yes, you will need a custom filter - it's a three-liner though:

```
@register.filter
def is_in(var, obj):
    return var in obj
```

Comment: can the list be in the template like: `{% if var in ['item1','item2','item3'] %}`

Comment: @Sevenearths I just tried it and can confirm that, as of Django 1.5.1, the list **cannot** be defined in the `if` statement like that.

Comment: how would we go about doing it then?

Comment: @laycat: we must compare with a list variable given inside the context. btw: how to avoid Django Template Language completely??

Answer (score 6):

Want to pass a comma separated string from the template? Create a custom templatetag:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def in_list(value, the_list):
    value = str(value)
    return value in the_list.split(',')
```

You can then call it like this:

```
{% if 'a'|in_list:'a,b,c,d,1,2,3' %}Yah!{% endif %}
```

It also works with variables:

```
{% if variable|in_list:'a,b,c,d,1,2,3' %}Yah!{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -3):

In Django 3...
It's simply by:

someHtmlPage.html

```
<html>
    {%if v.0%}
        <p>My string {{v}}</p>
    {%else%}
        <p>My another typy {{v}}</p>
    {%endif%}
</html>
```

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. In the example of your answer you are accessing a position in an array, not all positions.